# Hibernate Criteria Order not working

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

Am using hibernate criteria to fetch data from database. Now i need to fetch data based on `title` and `createdDate`, for that i added

```
if(condition){
 criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("title"));
}else{
 criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("createdDate"));
}
```

The issue is, its working for `createdDate` but not for `title`

Iam getting the result as `TEST,d1,ga,new,pre,ss,t` which should be like `d1,ga,new,pre,t,TEST`

**UPDATE**: The issue is with case, when i changed TEST to test its coming as proper.

Comment: I think that you can not achived that using Order. On sorting Strings uppercase letters are ordered before lowercase letters, due to having lower character values. Maybe you have to create your own comparator.

Comment: Down voting people at least show the manners to explain the problem..

Answer (score 1):

Try with criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("title").ignoreCase());

Comment: Yeah i found the issue is with case. But this didn't work for me. what to do?

Comment: that is weird. can you  update your question with your hibernate entity ?